# My set/dictionary-based script is stuttering...dictionary rehashing?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I've got a script that performs a large AI computation using sets and dictionaries, outputting a line every thousand states, and it has the tendency to stutter. The larger the searched space, the longer the stuttering, so I'm thinking it's probably the sets and dictionaries being rehashed. Is there anyway that I can make those classes over-allocate?

Comment: I doubt that, swap thrashing is much likelier reason. In any case you should profile instead of guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no way to force a dictionary to pre-allocate.  It might not be dictionary re-hashing, it could be the garbage collector.  There are functions in the `gc` module that you might be able to use to control or at least observe the collector behavior.

Comment: Hmmm... Could you elaborate on what the gc module might yield?

Comment: @Alex, among other things, you can turn automatic garbage collection off with `gc.disable()` and do manual collections with `gc.collect()`. There are also some gc debugging functions.